# Using Pandas to sum all values relating to a primary key and a secondary key

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a data frame that consists of three columns (id, buy/sell, amount). I would like to sum all the amounts for the buys and sells corresponding to each unique id.

[image]

I want the output to be a new data frame or pandas series that is as follows:

```
id         buy/sell     amount
blue          buy         9
              sell        5
green         buy         0
              sell        8
red           buy         3
              sell        12
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`results = df.groupby(['id', 'buy/sell']).sum()`

df is your original dataframe name.

Comment: I was trying that at first but it was not getting much luck. I solved the problem with pd.Grouper.